# Why nodes are not discovering each other in my private network?

Tags: private-blockchain, devp2p, node-discovery, bootnodes, discovery-protocol

I have created a private network with my own Genesis file. My private network has totally 4 systems(1 bootnode and other 3 are nodes).

I am running the bootnode in v4 using these two commands.

`bootnode -genkey bootnode.key` For generating private key (Only for first time)

`bootnode -nodekey bootnode.key --verbosity 6` Running bootnode.

This command gave me output like

`UDP listener up                            self=enode://acc1105.......@[::]:11111`

I am running other nodes using this command:

`geth --datadir ~/.ethereum/private --networkid 98765 --fast --rpc --rpcaddr=0.0.0.0 --rpcapi="admin,debug,eth,miner,net,personal,rpc,txpool,web3" --bootnodes enode://acc1105.......@BOOT_NODE_IP:11111 console`

I am getting `PING/v4, PONG/v4, FINDNODE/v4, NEIGHBORS/v4` outputs in bootnode. These 3 nodes are discovering each other for sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: Did you managed to solve it? My nodes are also not discovering each other, all of them have only 1 peer (bootnode).